# Using a class library in a ASP.NET next MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a website with the last version of MVC. My MVC project is running fine. I have a class library created with yeoman, it's running fine too.
I added my library in the MVC project.son

```
"dependencies": {
[...]
"ServicesAndDbContext": ""
},
```

If I run with the cmd dmx run it's ok BUT when I try to use my class library I have an error : "The type or namespace name 'ServicesAndDbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [dnx451]
"
This line appear when I write my : using ServicesAndDbContext;

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you have under "frameworks" on both project.json files?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
So in the project.son file for the class library I have:
    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
            }
        }
    }

And under theMVC project file I have :
    "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Thank you Bruno Garcia you found my problem.

dnx451 was missing under the framework section.